# Determine the sign of a 32 bit int

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

Using ONLY:

! ~ & ^ | + << >>

NO LOOPS

I need to determine the sign of a 32 bit integer and I need to return 1 if positive, 0 if 0 and -1 if negative.

Any ideas? I first thought about shifting over 31 bits and then looking at that sign but that obviously wont work and now I am kind of stuck.

Comment: I would only be able to tell if its negative. If its 0 then the number could be all zeros or it could be positive but I shifted those bits away.

Comment: Ah, I missed the requirement to also detect 0.

Comment: @Oli: it's not portable because the result of right-shifting a negative values is implementation-defined, and there's no requirement that it *either* 0-fill or sign-fill. That said, in practice it'll work, since all or almost all implementations do one or the other.

Comment: Note that neither `!` nor `+` is a bitwise operator.

Comment: @Steve: You could cast to unsigned first, I suppose.  Don't know if the arbitrary constraints allow this, though.

Comment: @Oli whatcha talkin' about ;)

Comment: @Oli: assuming that's supposed to be binary `+`. Unary `+` can reasonably be regarded as a bitwise operator ;-)

Comment: Are you allowed to do, e.g., `if (!x) return 0;`?

Comment: @Peter: could you look back through your notes and see what the course says about (a) 2's complement, and (b) the behaviour of `>>` for negative values? It could be that your homework assignment is giving you more than you realise (and hence more than you're giving us), by permitting you to assume 2's complement and/or a particular behavior of `>>`.

Comment: Jeez homework sure is a lot easier these days. I remember laboring on my own for hours to solve this stuff. Now just ask and 10 people are jumping to spoon feed you a solution.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know if this signed 32 bit integer type is actually `int` or if `int` is wider.

Comment: Its assumed it is a signed int, so right shifting is arithmatic.

Comment: C does not define a way to do this. On the other hand, most every machine is two's complement math, so while C specifically does not require any way for this to work, it should work on most real world hardware.

Comment: @Peter: it is not necessarily the case that right shift of signed types is arithmetic (see 6.5.7 in the standard). So if your professor has stated that right shift is arithmetic then that is important additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(x >> 31) | (((0 - x) >> 31) & 1)
```

How about this:

```
(x >> 31) | (((~x + 1) >> 31) & 1)
```

EDIT 2:

In response to issues (or rather nit-picking) raised in the comments...

Assumptions for these solutions to be valid:

1. x is of type 32-bit signed integer.
2. On this system, signed 32-bit integers are two's complement. (right-shift is arithmetic)
3. Wrap-around on arithmetic overflow.
4. For the first solution, the literal `0` is the same type as x.

Comment: Does this depend on a particular behaviour for `>>` when the left-hand operand is negative?

Comment: Assuming x is signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: The C standard leaves this as implementation-defined.  It could sign-extend, or zero-fill.  Which does your approach require?

Comment: `-` isn't in the list of allowed operators, no?

Comment: nice but I don't see - (minus sign) as an acceptable operation in his list.

Comment: @Jens: You are correct, but I think a negation can replaced with a ~ and +1. Lemme fix my solution.

Comment: you can make n negative by setting the high bit and adding: (n >> 31)| (((0 + (n|(1<<31))) >> 31) & 1)

Comment: Hm, only if you suppose that we have two's complement, no?

Comment: if we don't have two's complement then it's virtually unsolvable, no? I mean we have to make some assumption about what "negative" is right?

Comment: I'm gonna assume 2's complement. It'll be hard to make something that works for both 2's complement and something else.

Comment: Ah... I can fix that, gimme me a min. Good catch though.

Comment: @Kevin: Because `0 - INT_MIN` will overflow.

Comment: also your tricks wouldn't work if `int` is wider than 32 bit. then all your expressions would be done in that width and your shift wouldn't be the correct one.

Comment: In this problem do we also have to think about endianess ?

Comment: @Jens: hopefully we can ignore that possibility, since the question title (if not the body) specifies "32 bit int". But good catch!

Comment: @Muggen: no. Endianness has no effect on the results of any of the operators listed.

Comment: Hmm, I think my second solution still holds on INT_MIN. I'm still getting -1.

Comment: @Mystical, this is just by chance or goodwill of the compiler. Under your assumptions `~INT_MIN` is `INT_MAX` and with it `+1` overflows.

Comment: This is wrong. The result of `x>>31` is implementation-defined for negative `x`, there's no guarantee what its value is. It could be `0` for all negative `x` in a conforming C implementation. But I think this as a defect in the question -- I strongly suspect that (a) the expected answer uses a non-portable `>>`, and (b) the question as actually asked has no solution. So no downvote.

Comment: @Jens: Correct, but in this case, the overflow isn't harmful. The LHS of the expression will force the entire statement to evaluate to -1 anyways.

Comment: @Mystica: signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, it should always be considered harmful. To be honest, I don't know what they're teaching kids in school now, back in my day we read the standard. Yes, I'm grumpy and old, and don't even have the excuse of being old enough that back in my day there *was* no standard ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Signed left shift isn't defined in the standard?

Comment: @Mystical, this is not `||` so the evaluation is not short circuited and in particular the compiler is allowed to evaluate the subexpressions in any order. For `INT_MIN` you have UB.

Comment: IIRC signed left shift for negative values leads to UB

Comment: Short-circuiting doesn't matter. You're ORing against a bunch of ones. The result is always a bunch of 1s. So it doesn't matter whether the RHS is defined or not as long as it's of type signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: @Mysticial: correct. 6.5.7/4: "... E1 << E2 ... If E1 has signed type and non-negative value, and `E1 * 2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Mysticial: "You're ORing against a bunch of ones". No. Undefined behavior means that your computer might have exploded before it got a chance to OR anything with anything. For the very rare implementations that object to arithmetic overflow, admittedly a hardware exception or power cycle is more likely than actually exploding, but still that's different from a result of `0xffffffff`.

Comment: @Sorry, I meant right-shift. Anyways, I think this discussion is already well beyond the scope of this HW problem. As far as I can tell, the solution I gave works for all cases in a modern compiler.

Comment: @Mysticial: for right shift it's implementation-defined rather than UB (6.5.7/5, "... E1 >> E2 ... If E1 has signed type and negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined". So it will not explode, but is not guaranteed to give the result you want.

Comment: @Steve, if you insist. What's your solution?

Comment: Then I'm gonna add a list of assumptions to my solution to make it clear.

Comment: @Mysticial: as I already stated, I think that as phrased here the question doesn't have a solution. I haven't proved that to my own satisfaction, though. Both your solutions require 2's complement and arithmetic shift, the first also requires wraparound on overflow. Of those, I'm not certain that "a modern compiler" necessarily uses arithmetic shift, but I basically agree about the others with the caveat that for example `gcc` has `-f` options that control overflow, so it's up to the user whether it's "modern" or not by that definition :-)

Comment: @Steve: Fine, but we never saw the actual text of the question. It could have been a lot more clear. And downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @Mysticial: agreed, we don't know here whether the error is the questioner's (not providing us with all the assumptions that the professor allows), or the professor's (not understanding the full range of behavior permitted by the standard). Or mine (failing to see how to solve it portably within the stated constraints).

Comment: Suppose you could do something like this to offset those cases where int != 32-bits: `( x >> ( sizeof( int ) * 8 - 1 ) ) | ( ( ( 0 - x ) >> ( sizeof( int ) * 8 - 1 ) ) & 1 )`

Answer (score 6):

If conditionals (not `if` statements) and subtraction are allowed, the simplest & cleaner solution (IMO) is:

```
int sign = (v > 0) - (v < 0);
```

Not using subtraction (and assuming `int` is 32 bits):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

int process(int v) {
    int is_negative = (unsigned int)v >> 31; // or sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1
    int is_zero = !v;
    int is_positive = !is_negative & !is_zero;
    int sign = (is_positive + ~is_negative) + 1;
    return sign;
}

int main() {
    assert(process(0) == 0);
    printf("passed the zero test\n");
    for (int v = INT_MIN; v < 0; v++) {
        assert(process(v) == -1);
    }
    printf("passed all negative tests\n");
    for (int v = 1; v < INT_MAX; v++) {
        assert(process(v) == +1);
    }
    printf("passed all positive tests\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's are the results:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c99 && ./test && echo $#
passed zero test
passed all negative tests
passed all positive tests
0
```

Comment: The question specified no loops.  IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: @Carey: please, understand the code before casting any votes. Note the loop is there just to provide input values (`v`) for testing the algorithm.

Comment: I understand the code.  If your solution involved only bitwise operators as the question required I wouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @Carey: I split it into a separate function to make it clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please, show me that requirement (only bitwise operators). I don't see it in the question. So far you've raised 2 different arguments, and both are invalid.

Comment: @Carey: that's ok, no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use bitwise operators for that?

```
int get_sign(int value)
{
    return (value < 0) ? -1 : (int)(value != 0);
}
```

If you absolutely have to use bitwise operators, then you can use the `&` operator to check for negative values, no shifting needed:

```
int get_sign(int value)
{
    return (value & 0x80000000) ? -1 : (int)(value != 0);
}
```

If you want to shift:

```
int get_sign(int value)
{
    return ((value >> 31) & 1) ? -1 : (int)(value != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more convoluted, but there is this:

```
(~((x >> 31) & 1) + 1) | (((~x + 1) >> 31) & 1)
```

This should take care of the ambiguity of whether the shift will fill in 1's or 0's

For a breakdown, any place we have this construct:

```
(z >> 31) & 1
```

Will result in a 1 when negative, and a 0 otherwise.

Any place we have:

```
(~z + 1)
```

We get the negated number (-z)

So the first half will produce a result of 0xFFFFFFFF (-1) iff x is negative, and the second half will produce 0x00000001 (1) iff x is positive.  Bitwise or'ing them together will then produce a 0x00000000 (0) if neither is true.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
int getsign(int n)
{
  return (!!n) + (~((n >> 30) & 2) + 1);
}
```

..for 32-bit signed int, 2's complement only.

`!!n` gives 1 if `n` is nonzero.
`((n >> 30) & 2)` gives 2 iff the high bit (sign) is set.  The bitwise NOT and +1 take the 2's complement of this, giving -2 or 0.
Adding gives -1 (1 + -2) for negative values, 0 (0 + 0) for zero, and +1 (1 + 0) for positive values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the implementation defines arithmetic right shift:

```
(x>>31) | !!x
```

Unlike Mystical's answer, there is no UB.

And, if you want to also support systems where right shift is defined to be arithmetic shift:

```
~!(x>>31)+1 | !!x
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I omitted a `!` in the second version. It should be:

```
~!!(x>>31)+1 | !!x
```

This version is still dependent on the implementation being twos complement and having *either* arithmetic *or* logical right-shift, i.e. if the implementation-defined behavior were something else entirely it could break. However, if you change the types to *unsigned* types, all of the implementation-defined behavior vanishes and the result is `-1U`, `0U`, or `1U` depending on the "sign" (high bit and zero/nonzero status) of `x`.

Comment: +1 for the most elegant solution so far, although it is not a real one, since it still depending on the type of right shift that the architecture provides. Wouldn't it be able to combine the two to a unique solution?

Comment: Correct, right-shift in signed integers with negative values has unspecified behavior in C99. Btw, your second example lacks some parenthesis?

Comment: @jweyrich: it's not unspecified, it's implementation-defined. In practice, we know that all implementations we care about are either arithmetic or logical right shift (if it was unspecified, they wouldn't even have to be consistent, but they have to define the result and understandably they seem always choose one or the other). In principle, an implementation can define that `-1 >> 1 == 0`, which is why I don't think it's possible to solve the problem without some additional assumptions. Perhaps stating those assumptions is part of the homework, of course.

Comment: The second expression doesn't seem to give the right answer for `0`.

Comment: Typo, or at least I'll use that as my excuse for a logic error. :-) It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the absolute ideal way to do things, but I think it's reasonably portable and at least somewhat simpler than what you had:

```
#define INT_BITS 32

int sign(int v) { 
    return (!!v) | -(int)((unsigned int)v >> (INT_BITS-1));
}
```

Comment: @Mysticial: There is a minor problem: `-` isn't actually allowed on this question, so technically it's not really allowed as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitri's idea could be simplified to (!!x) - ((x >> 30) & 2)

And just to give one more cryptic solution:

```
~!x & ((-((unsigned) x >> 31)) | !!x)
```