# How to convert any number to 1 or -1 with sign kept via bitwise operator?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Given any number, for example 345.678 and -345.678, what I want is to convert 345.678 to 1 and -345.678 to -1.
Basically I want to convert any number to 1 or -1 with the sign kept via bit-wise operator.

Although I don't know why, I can convert any number into -1 like this:

```
345.678 | -1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you *have* to use bitwise operations to convert and keep the sign?

Comment: Why not a simple ternary operation like `(value > 0) ? 1 : -1`?

Comment: Definitely non-trivial, given that bitwise operators convert the 64 bit floating point number to a 32 bit integer by chopping off the most significant bits.

Comment: Minus one is made of 1s in binary, that's why the result of `number | -1` is always -1

Comment: I doubt there is a way to get sign using single bitwise operator. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341458/351705 this might work for you. But it involves shifts and arithmetic operators.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that it's not possible using only bitwise operators. Look forward to someone proving me wrong.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it *should* be...I think. But I can't figure it out - my brain is currently melting. Thinking about bitwise operations doesn't help that, either.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Using OP's requirements (ie ignoring 0 case) the solution would be `const  sign = x => x >> 31 | (~x >> 31 & 1); console.log([-323.23, 0, 2343.4].map(sign))`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko worth posting as an answer, I think.

Comment: @VLAZ Or closing as duplicate. I've simple used C solution from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341458/351705 :)

Comment: Anyway Yury's answer has the same limitations as mine for range -1 > x > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the idea of this question [sign function in C using bit operators only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24855863/)

```
(x >> 31) & 1
```

and adjust the result by taking bitwise OR instead of bitwise AND to get `1` instead of `0` and `-1` instead of `1`

```js
const sign = x => (x >> 31) | 1;

console.log(sign(345.678));
console.log(sign(-345.678));
```

Comment: Wrong result for -0.345678, any number in interval `-1 < n < 0` you will get wrong result.

Comment: that is, because bitwise operators floors the value, so yes it is wrong for smaller values.

Answer (score 1):

For any **integer** `N` in the `[-2147483648, +2147483647]` interval, you can do:

```
(N >> -1) | 1
```

It will result in -1 if `N` is negative, and 1 if `N` is positive.
For zero, the resulting value is 1.

### Note:

It does not work for decimals in interval `(-1, 0)` (the resulting value is 1 instead of -1). However it should work for any other decimal numbers.

If you want it to work for **every** decimal numbers, the fix is simple:

```
(Math.floor( N ) >> -1) | 1
```

But then you're not using only bitwise operators.

Comment: You could also just do `Math.sign` but OP is asking for bitwise operation.

Comment: Multiplication and addition are not bitwise.

Comment: It was not clear we should only use bitwise operators. But I'll come back with an improved version

Comment: Now only using bitwise operators.

Comment: What does `number >> -1` actually do? It doesn't seem to be shifting, unless it's a shorthand for `number >> 31`?

Comment: It does the same as 31, just it is more universal in case one day the JavaScript engine switches to 64 bits integers.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of that. I tried few things and it seemed to result with all `0`s (0) for positive numbers and all `1`s (-1) for negatives, so I was confused.

Comment: Actually I noticed that (-1).toString(2) equals the string "-1" in JavaScript. Then I noticed that if I replace -1 by certain numerical strings, it works as well. For example: `(-1234 >> "99999") | 1`. So I'm wondering if my `>> -1` is working for different reasons than I thought.

Comment: Is JS switching to 64bit integers a real concern? It would basically break the web

Comment: No, of course, it isn't a real concern. Still, it is shorter :)

Comment: It works with other numbers than 31 as well: 30, 31, 62, 63, 94, 95, 126, 127, 158, 159...